# Lemke Howson Algorithm, Whats is the meaning of projection to polytop?

Tags: game-theory, polytopes, nash-equilibrium

I'm reading about Lemke-Howson algorithm from "Algorithmic Game Theory" book, in the exercise part there is question as follow:

Show that the “projection” to polytope P, say, of a LH path from (x, y) to (x',y')
in P × Q is also a path in P from x to x'. Hence, if (x, y) is an equilibrium, where can x be on that projected path?

But I don't get what's the purpose of the question, Can someone please just tell me what's the meaning of the question? What does it mean by "Projection to polytope"?